# Tensorflow Expanding Placeholder Dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a 2-d placeholder tensor with dimensions of (2,2). How can I expand the columns (same number dimensions) so that the new tensor is (2,3) and assign a constant value to the new column?

For example, the current data may look like 
[[2,2], [2,2]]

And I want to transform through tensorflow to (prepending a constant of 1):
[[1,2,2], [1,2,2]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) op to concatenate a constant with your placeholder:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[2, 2])
prefix_column = tf.constant([[1], [1]])
expanded_placeholder = tf.concat([prefix_column, placeholder], axis=1)
```